# Separating Systems from the ECS (Entity Component System) Manager in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, types, void-pointers, entity-component-system

I am currently making an Entity-Component-System program as a way to learn C++ (I know that's probably not the recommended way but I'm having fun). It's going well so far but I am hoping to make some more improvements to it.

Each system is currently added to the ECS manager as a `std::function` along with a signature of what components it requires run. My current strategy is iterate through each system and entity and if the component signatures match then the system function is called with the entity id as a parameter.

```
// System function
static Game::runSystem(Manager & mngr, int id) {

    ComponentA * a = mngr.getComponent<ComponentA>(id);
    ComponentB * b = mngr.getComponent<ComponentB>(id);

    // Do something with a and b

}
```

This function is attached to the Manager by this method:

```
// Definition
template<typename...Args>
void Manager::addSystem(std::function<void(XManager & mngr, int id)> f); // A bitmask signature is generated based on the template

// Use
manager.addSystem<ComponentA, ComponentB>(Game::runSystem);
```

`ComponentA` and `ComponentB` are simply generic types. I can even have a component be a `float` or `int` if I need to. When using `getComponent<T>()`, these are cast into the appropriate pointers.

This all works perfectly but what ends up happening is I have to include the header file for the Manager for each System and I would prefer for them to not be tied to each other (I guess this would be separation of concerns).

Preferably each process would end up looking similar to this:

```
static Game::runSystem(ComponentA * a, ComponentB * b) {
    // Do something with a and b
}
```

The only thing the System would need to know about are the component pointers for the specific entity on which it is processing.

I am currently storing components in an `std::unordered_map` according to a bitmask of its Type. When a component is needed, the template provides the type which I am able to make a bitmask from and then cast it. I am unsure if it is possible to store the Type of the component for casting so I think each component will have to be passed to the function as a void pointer. But C++ doesn't let me implicitly cast from a `void*` to another pointer without knowing the type. Is there a way that I can store the Type of each component for casting later when needed?

I'm thinking I can possibly just have the function definition with `void*` for each component the system requires, but intuitively that seems like a bad idea. It's not type safe at all and I won't be able to know what parameters it needs by looking at the function declaration.

How can I pass a reference to a function that can take any number of pointers of any type? Is there a way to do this via templates or can I implicitly cast a void pointer without knowing the type? I am open to other strategies as well.

Comment: Type erasure is the better alternative to void pointers, but that may be either impossible or overkill depending on your exact situation (which I can't wrap my head around based just on the code fragments and text). Can you show more code? At least the minimal declarations of all involved types?

Comment: The way I implement a ECS is that the System owns the components and the Entities only have some form of reference to it (usually an ID). Then the main ECS manager just has to iterate all Systems and call their `Update` function (provided via an interface), everything else is handled inside the system itself.

Comment: So if each system owns their components, who owns, say, a "position" component which can be useful with several systems such as physics, drawing, or navigation? My goal with this is that each system only needs a reference to the component it is dealing with. That way it doesn't need to know anything about the Manager.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with ECS is each person has their own interpretation of how they see it working.

> The only thing the System would need to know about are the component pointers for the specific entity on which it is processing.

I disagree with this, at least with how its effectively written.

A system should not operate within the context of an entity.  In fact, that's irrelevant.  A system is interested in component tuples.  In most cases those tuples are a projection on an entity, but that's just semantics.

> This all works perfectly but what ends up happening is I have to include the header file for the Manager for each System and I would prefer for them to not be tied to each other (I guess this would be separation of concerns)

It is one thing to be concerned that one game system implementation does not depend on another.  This is important because the idea behind ECS is to provide a solution where "code just works" even if an entity does not possess a given component or tuple of components or if a given game system gets disabled.

In my implementation, systems include the entity system header.  This is primarily by design because I prefer that entity data and component data be managed in a central place, much like a database.  Its the purpose of these game systems to manipulate that central database based on game logic only.

A very simple system that sends an event upon death might look like this

```
void DeathSystem::update(const FrameContext& context) {
  const auto components = getEntitySystem().getComponents<AttributeComponent>();
  for ( const AttributeComponent &component : components ) {
    if ( component.getAttributeAsLong(HEALTH) == 0 ) {
      sendEvent( EntityDiedEvent( component.getEntityId() ) );
    }
  }
}
```

Each system implements an *interface* that is designed to give the ECS framework as much information to know what dependencies a system has with one another, how to obviously call the various lifecycle callbacks, etc.  This decouples the concern that during startup, systems can be registered in any order, added or removed at any time during run-time and "it just works".

> I'm thinking I can possibly just have the function definition with void* for each component the system requires, but intuitively that seems like a bad idea. It's not type safe at all and I won't be able to know what parameters it needs by looking at the function declaration.

I think you should shift your mindset here.  This higher level class that is calling these game systesms, you're making assumptions about what the system needs, which I disagree with.  You should provide the game system with a means to access whatever it needs and let it drive what it does.

You could easily write a system like this.  Whether something like this is ideal or even useful is debatable, but delegating what a system does to itself just makes the code much easier IMHO.

```
void LaggingSystem::update(const FrameContext& context) {
  if ( context.getTimeSinceLastFrame() >= maxLagTolerance ) {
    const auto &widget = getLagAlertWidget();
    if ( !widget.isVisible() ) {
      widget.show();
    }
  }
}
```